# why custom validator method not firing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have created a custom validation, which I want to use to compare 2 select boxes, but the additonal method is not firing not sure how to fix it?
here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ughCm/97/
On change of select value it is not firing the 'comaremodelyear' method, even not on .valid().

here is the code

```
$.validator.addMethod("comparemodalyear", function(value, element, param) {
    alert('h');
    return true;    
}, "From year must be greater!");

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#savebtn').click(function() {
        var test = $("#experiment").valid();
    });

});
```

html code:

```
<form id="experiment" action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" required name="fine" />
<select comparemodalyear name="testingA">
    <option value="1">Val1</option>
    <option value="2">Val2</option>
</select>
    <button id="savebtn" type="button">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Use this in class like <select class="comparemodalyear" name="testingA">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it as a class not as an attribute

```
<select class="comparemodalyear" name="testingA">
    <option value="1">Val1</option>
    <option value="2">Val2</option>
</select>
```

then

```
$.validator.addClassRules('comparemodalyear', {
    comparemodalyear: true
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xqf7j7pL/)

---

If you don't want to pass a custom value to the rule, then there is no need for `addClassRules()` because the `addMethod()` makes an internal call to `addClassRules()` based on `method.length < 3` condition, where `method.length` is the [count of arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) to the validate method

```
$.validator.addMethod("comparemodalyear", function (value, element) {
    alert('h');
    return true;
}, "From year must be greater!");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xqf7j7pL/2/)

Comment: From ur fiddle I see u have also added $('#form').validate(), Can I call this multiple times? Its a dynamic form and I need to call this on click of button every time, is it safe?

Comment: @coure2011 you can ignore that... not really required